# System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain

Tags: .net, docker, https

I am getting the following when I run my dotnet application docker container.

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
       ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain
```

I have added my CA Certificates

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
COPY cacerts/ForgeRockIDAMIntermediate.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/aspnet/ForgeRockIDAMIntermediate.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["PingFederateQRCodeServerApp.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./PingFederateQRCodeServerApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "PingFederateQRCodeServerApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "PingFederateQRCodeServerApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PingFederateQRCodeServerApp.dll"]
```

So not sure why it is failing.

Cleaned out my dev certificates using

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
```

removed the `pfx` created from my roaming profile.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Seems I should have read the details more because when I added my Root CA Certificate it started to work

I added to my `Dockerfile`

```
COPY cacerts/ForgeRockIDAMRoot.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/aspnet/ForgeRockIDAMRoot.crt
```

So it becomes

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 49159
COPY cacerts/ForgeRockIDAMRoot.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/aspnet/ForgeRockIDAMRoot.crt
COPY cacerts/ForgeRockIDAMIntermediate.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/aspnet/ForgeRockIDAMIntermediate.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["PingFederateQRCodeServerApp.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./PingFederateQRCodeServerApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "PingFederateQRCodeServerApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "PingFederateQRCodeServerApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PingFederateQRCodeServerApp.dll"]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).